# $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable $C$: Cantor set then $f^{-1}[C]$ Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

True or false: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $C$ is the Cantor set then $f^{-1}[C]$ Lebesgue measurable.

I believe this is true because $C$ is closed and so is a Borel set so is Borel measurable thus is Lebesgue measurable.

I wanted to post to check because I know there is an example using the Cantor function to construct  a non-Lebesgue measurable set.

Comment: as far as I know, it's measurable.

Comment: The conclusion is correct but whether your argument is correct or not depends on what you mean by $f$ being measurable.

Comment: If you mean $f$ is a Lebesgue or Borel measurable function, your conclusion and your argument are correct.